# Update jsf growl message from load method of LazyDataModel

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces

I need to display a message when LazyDataModel load method loads the data. I am using primefaces growl to display the message and updating it from load method using the below code, but It is not working (not seeing any message on UI). Please suggest what I am doing wrong, It seems something related to the asynchronous behaviour of load method but I am not sure how to fix it.

JSF Bean -

```
@ManagedBean(name = "cData")
@ViewScoped
public class DataPage implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2193735279937686495L;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("growl-sticky", new
                  FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Sticky Message",
                  "Message Content from init"));
        loadData();
    }
    
    private void loadData() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("growl-sticky", new
                  FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Sticky Message",
                  "Message loadData before load"));
        setMobiles(new LazyDataModel<Mobile>() {
            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public List<Mobile> load(int first, int pageSize,

                    String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder,

                    Map<String, Object> filters) {
                List<Mobile> data = new DataRepo().getMobileData();
                mobiles.setRowCount(data.size());
                
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("growl-sticky", new
                          FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Sticky Message",
                          "Message Content from load"));
                return data;
            }

            @Override
            public Mobile getRowData(String rowKey) {
                // some code
            }

            @Override
            public Object getRowKey(Mobile object) {
                // some code
            }
        });
    }

    public LazyDataModel<Mobile> getMobiles() {
        return mobiles;
    }

    public void setMobiles(LazyDataModel<Mobile> mobiles) {
        this.mobiles = mobiles;
    }

    private LazyDataModel<Mobile> mobiles = null;

}
```

xhtml page -

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
xmlns:h = "http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:c = "http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>DataTable tag Example</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h3>Mobile Details</h3>
    
    <h:form>
    <c:metadata>
        <c:viewAction action="#{cData.showSticky}" />
    </c:metadata>
    
    <p:growl id="growl-sticky" showDetail="true" sticky="true" autoUpdate="true"/>
    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{cData.showSticky}"
        update="growl-sticky" value="Info" style="width: 10rem"
        styleClass="ui-button-help" />
    
        <h:dataTable value="#{cData.mobiles}" var="mobile" border="2" paginator="true" rows="10"
             lazy="true">
            <h:column>
                <c:facet name="header">Name</c:facet>
                    #{mobile.companyname}
                </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <c:facet name="header">Model Number</c:facet>
                    #{mobile.modelnumber}
                </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <c:facet name="header">Color</c:facet>
                    #{mobile.color}
                </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <c:facet name="header">Quantity</c:facet>
                    #{mobile.quantity}
                </h:column>
            <h:column>
                <c:facet name="header">Price</c:facet>
                    #{mobile.price}
                </h:column>

        </h:dataTable>
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Define "not working"

Comment: @LajosArpad I am not seeing any message on UI on page load.

Comment: Do you have errors?

Comment: @LajosArpad nope

Answer (score 2):

The issue why your message doesn't show up is because of the phase when Load is called.  Explanation and workaround below.

The load method is invoked in RENDER_RESPONSE phase, which is inconvenient because error messages could occur here and they would not typically be rendered because p:messages are in most cases rendered as one of first components.

Issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3501

Workaround: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3501#issuecomment-469731529